# Windows version of "Netem" (to simulate slow network connection)?

Tags: .net, windows, sockets, networking

I am testing a windows based network application, and I need to see how the server will perform when there is packet loss, congestion, or just a very slow, unreliable connection.

It's a real pity it's windows based. I'm looking for something similar to the linux tool ["Netem"](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem), which does exactly what I need.

Preferably, I need this tool to work on the loopback.

Comment: Good discussion on throttling connections here:

http://superuser.com/questions/330501/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-firefox

Comment: @Paul Unfortunately, it's not a browser based application.

Comment: @Paul : link broken

Comment: @sandwood - https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/11/07/simulate-slow-connections-with-the-network-throttling-tool/ - might be of use now. Looks like the link has been removed from superuser for some reason. Also here's  a scraped version of the sme thing: 

https://www.queryxchange.com/q/2_330501/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-or-limit-the-bandwidth-that-firefox-can-use/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal is to setup a Linux machine with a Windows VM for testing the application. Doing it in this way it should be possible to change the quality of the appropriate interface which is connected to the vm. For sure it is virtualized and not native but maybe it is sufficient for you.

Comment: Amazing, How didn't I think of that? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @xyz312, I did't got your answer clearly. Can you describe more on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate slow network connections on windows, [ipfw+dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) has a Windows port that works fantastically. It lets you set up 'pipes' which match certain network traffic, and those pipes can pass traffic that is then  delayed, dropped, or bandwidth limited
Examples from the website:

Limit the total incoming TCP traffic to 2Mbit/s, and UDP to 300Kbit/s

```
ipfw add pipe 2 in proto tcp
ipfw add pipe 3 in proto udp
ipfw pipe 2 config bw 2Mbit/s
ipfw pipe 3 config bw 300Kbit/s
```

Limit incoming traffic to 300Kbit/s for each host on network 10.1.2.0/24

```
ipfw add pipe 4 src-ip 10.1.2.0/24 in
ipfw pipe 4 config bw 300Kbit/s queue 20 mask dst-ip 0x000000ff
```

Simulate an ADSL link to the moon:

```
ipfw add pipe 3 out
ipfw add pipe 4 in
ipfw pipe 3 config bw 128Kbit/s queue 10 delay 1000ms
ipfw pipe 4 config bw 640Kbit/s queue 30 delay 1000ms
```